# "DontNeedGithubAccount" instead of username when pushing to Github with Intellij Idea

Tags: github, intellij-idea, git-push

I'm trying to push to my github account from Intellij. Everything is working correctly. However, when I go from the browser into Github, instead of my github username the name "DontNeedGithubAccount" is being shown for the commits. I'm surprised that Google only has a few entries when searching for "DontNeedGithubAccount" but none of them are even remotely helpful.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that something you did enter into the configuration of some other git client SW? Maybe so long ago you don't recall it? (I don't have I-J, only Android Studio, and when I search settings for git, I can see some plugin to add github account (can't try myself at this PC - but maybe you have it configured like this?), and regular git plugin (can't see username config). But I usually check the `.git/config` file of the folder on disc myself in text editor, configuring it manually... check also that one (and your `$userdir/.git/config` or something similar for your "global" git settings)

Comment: i.e. I guess your user name in some git config looks like that, instead of what you have on your github. BTW, IIRC, if you want "verified" GPG signed commits, you have to have both names/emails (on github web, and on your PC) identical (and of course you need the correct private key, and sign the commit, but just signing with different user name did made it fail I think, if I'm not confusing it with something else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ped7g, I figured it out: In your git config (.git/Config), you need to add

```
[user]
      name = github_username
      email = github_email@example.com
```

You can also achieve this by doing (use --local for current or --global for all repos)

```
git config --local user.name github_username
git config --local user.email github_email@example.com
```

The username must match the one on Github. If you additionally provide the same email you can click on your username and get to your account.

[image]

Comment: Turns out `DontNeedGithubAccount` was not 100% true then.